# regex pattern for comparing directories

Tags: regex, bash, conditional-statements

Im working on a conditional block in BASH that prevents users from using both /usr/ or /usr/local as their install prefix. The block below works if the prefix is typed in exactly /usr/ or /usr/local by the user, hence the need for regex. Every regex pattern I have used seems to not want to work. They work great for matching files but directory names, not so much.

Ideas?

```
if [[ "$prefix" == "/usr/" || "$prefix" == "/usr/local/" ]];then
    echo "You're holding it wrong!"
    echo 'The install prefix cannot be in "/usr/" or "/usr/local/"'
    echo "Is the install prefix defined?"
    echo ""
    exit 1
fi
```

Thanks,

Brandon

Comment: Is `/usr/acceptable` acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canonicalize the path with `readlink -f` (or `realpath`) before comparing it:

```
prefix=$(readlink -f "$prefix")

# note: no trailing /
if [[ "$prefix" == "/usr" || "$prefix" == "/usr/local" ]];then
```

This has the added advantage of also catching symlinks to `/usr` and `/usr/local` and silliness such as `/opt/../usr`. If you want to forbid all locations under `/usr`, use (for example)

```
# note: trailing / is back. This is to make it possible to match for /usr/
# in the beginning so strange directories such as /usrfoo are not caught.
prefix=$(readlink -f "$prefix")/

if [ "$prefix" != "${prefix##/usr/}" ]; then
  # there was a /usr/ prefix to remove, so the directory was in /usr
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. My script needs to work on RHEL5/6/7 and Ubuntu 1204/1404 + many more :)

Comment: @rici Oh, okay. I added a note about `readlink`, which you can use to the same effect. `readlink` is part of coreutils, so I think it should be available everywhere. Hmm...although, at a second glance, so is `realpath`. `readlink` is older, though.

Comment: I just checked, and realpath seems to be installed on RHEL5/6/7 and Ubuntu 1204. I think it would be save to use.

Comment: `realpath` appears to have a long and convoluted history of several not entirely compatible versions, so I think I'll change the example to favor `readlink -f` and leave a side note about realpath. For this case, either should work, though.

Comment: @Wintermute thanks, I added the readlink check and it makes the regex matching more robust.

Answer (score 1):

You can just check for starting text `/usr/` using glob pattern

```
[[ "$prefix" == "/usr/"* ]]
```

`*` in the end is glob to match anything after `/usr/`.

No need to check for `"/usr/local/"` since that is also starting with `/usr/`.

Comment: But didn't OP write to block `/usr/ `?

Comment: True. I just saw where my error was. I guess it would help if I posted example of what regex patters I have tried :) The error was I was putting the * wildcard inside the strong quotes, not outside. Thanks!

Comment: I just tested this and it works:

if [[ "$prefix" == "/usr/"* ]]

I don't want users to be able to install code in /usr/* because it may/will break other developers when they build their code.

I have also added a force argument so developers may still install in /usr/* if for example they are installing on a production server, and having the code in /usr/* is desired. Albeit this would require sudo access which I don't just dole out :)

Thanks all!

Comment: @BrandonEss: so a silly user will user `/./usr/` for his prefix. If you're using this solution, you certainly don't need to bother adding a force argument! `:D`.